# Reverse complement a string in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bioinformatics

I am writing a pyspark bio oriented application and in one of the steps I have a spark dataframe of extracted dna sequences. For those that appear in the minus strand I would like to reverse complement.

I was able to perform the task with udf but I understand that this limits sparks ability to be efficient (specially since this is pyspark). This also causes OOM issues.

Reversing a string is easy as it is a built-in functionality but I cannot find a method to complement the dna bases (A->T, G->C, N->N, ...).

Is there a spark sql way to do it? If not, does it help to implement it in java and register it as a udf in python?

I am running on EMR 6.20 so it's based on spark 3

**Edit:**
example data as requested. Lets say I have a dataframe with the following data:

```
+------------+
|    sequence|
+------------+
|ATTGCCATGCCA|
|GTTCGTTA    |
|ATNNGGRRG   |
+------------+
```

The expected output should be:

```
+------------+
|    sequence|
+------------+
|TAACGGTACGGT|
|CAAGCAAT    |
|TANNCCYYC   |
+------------+
```

The mapping is based on [IUPAC notations for DNA](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms/iupac.html) and complement means the complementary base for DNA pairing (A<->T, G<->C).

**Edit (solution):**
Thanks @mck for the solution. A version of the reverse complement call assuming an upper case sequence (otherwise just add lowercase options)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'stranded_sequence',
    F.translate(
        F.reverse(F.col('sequence')),
        'ACGTRYSWKMBDHVN',
        'TGCAYRSWMKVHDBN'
    )
)
```

If you have a `strand` column in your df like me you can even switch case it as such:

```py
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'stranded_sequence',
    F.when(
        F.col('strand') == '-',
        F.translate(
            F.reverse(F.col('sequence')),
            'ACGTRYSWKMBDHVN',
            'TGCAYRSWMKVHDBN'
        )
    ).otherwise(F.col('sequence'))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `translate`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('sequence', F.translate('sequence', 'ATCGRY', 'TAGCYR'))

df2.show()
+------------+
|    sequence|
+------------+
|TAACGGTACGGT|
|    CAAGCAAT|
|   TANNCCYYC|
+------------+
```

To account for all possible bases, you can just extend the strings to something like

```
ATCGRYSWKM...
TAGCYRWSMK...
```